# Where is my error in this incorrect proof of Wolstenholme's theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove for a prime $p>3$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{-1}\equiv 0\pmod {p^2}$$ Now since the inverse of any number in $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ is in $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ we get $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{-1}\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}\equiv 0\pmod p$$
In fact it is never $0\pmod{p^2}$. Can you help me find the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: If you explain *how* you made the incorrect inference "it is never $0\pmod{ p^2}$" then we might be able to debug your argument. I doubt the answer you accepted  does that. The question will be closed (and likely deleted) without that missing crucial context.

Comment: I thought that since $\sum k^{-1}\equiv p(p-1)/2\pmod p$ and $p(p-1)/2\not\equiv 0\pmod {p^2}$ then $\sum k^{-1}\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$ @BillDubuque

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mistake is that the inverse mod $p$ is in $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$, but that's not the same as the inverse mod $p^2$.

Comment: For example, mod 25, the inverses of 1,2,3,4 are 1,13,17,19.